# Why typescript libraries use d.ts instead of .ts in types field?

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

I'm just wondering why library should generate `d.ts` when library already written in `.ts`

typescript library usually compile like this.

```
my-package/
 - package.json
 - lib/
     - index.ts
     - hello.ts
 - dist/
     - index.js
     - index.d.ts
     - hello.js
     - hello.d.ts
```

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/"
}
```

But how about just use ts file in `types` field?

```
my-package/
 - package.json
 - lib/
     - index.ts
     - hello.ts
 - dist/
     - index.js
     - hello.js
```

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.ts"
}
```

could ts type differ to d.ts type? I want to use fast compiler like esbuild or swc for library but declaration generation is still a bottlenect point..

Answer (score 0):

Declarations can be different from source code, in that typescript will write out inferred types, it will expand out some types aliases in type declarations. Ideally the behavior of the types should be the same (although there are cases where it might not be).

There are benefits for library authors to provide d.ts files, namely:

1. Compiler performance is better since Typescript does not have to check library code
2. Users that have `skipLibCheck` can also skip type checking on declarations, further improving build times.

If you are interested in improving declaration emit, there is a feature in the works called [`isolatedDeclarations`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47947) that will allow you to use any tool to emit declarations as long as all your module exports don't use inference.